# ASP.NET Dynamically built HtmlTable not updating server-side after Javascript changes and postback

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, postback, code-behind

I have a jagged array (int[][] arr) in the server-side.

The table you're seeing in the picture below represents the content of the array (1=red, 0=white and -1=black) and I created it dynamically via the code-behind (C#).

After a click on a table cell, its color changes via the javascript script you're seeing below, and I want to update that change to the server-side (i.e. update my array so that next time I run the algorithm, it would take the changes into consideration).

I've tried everything but nothing seems to work so far. One of the main problems is that I lose the information that the HtmlTable holds after postback.

Any suggestions on how to implement this? Thanks!

[image]

Here's the main part of the client-side code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var red = "#e74c3c";
    var black = "#000000";
    var white = "#FFFFFF";


    function cSwap(cell) { //swaps the colors of the cells
        if (cell.bgColor == red) { //red to white
            cell.style.transitionDuration = "0.1s";
            cell.bgColor = white;

            for (i = 0; i < tableContent.rows.length; i++) {
                for (j = 0; j < tableContent.rows[i].cells.length; j++) {
                    if (cell.id == tableContent.rows[i].cells[j].id) {
                        tableContent.rows[i].cells[j].bgColor = white;
                    }
                }
            }

        }
        else if (cell.bgColor == black) { //black to red
            cell.style.transitionDuration = "0.1s";
            cell.bgColor = red;
            for (i = 0; i < tableContent.rows.length; i++) {
                for (j = 0; j < tableContent.rows[i].cells.length; j++) {
                    if (cell.id == tableContent.rows[i].cells[j].id) {
                        tableContent.rows[i].cells[j].bgColor = red;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        else if (cell.bgColor == white) { //white to black
            cell.style.transitionDuration = "0.1s";
            cell.bgColor = black;
            for (i = 0; i < tableContent.rows.length; i++) {
                for (j = 0; j < tableContent.rows[i].cells.length; j++) {
                    if (cell.id == tableContent.rows[i].cells[j].id) {
                        tableContent.rows[i].cells[j].bgColor = black;    
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

</script>

<title></title>
</head>
<body style="height: 287px; width: 1236px">
    <form id="form1" runat="server">

        <div draggable="auto" style="height: 618px">
            <div id="AutoAssignDiv" draggable="auto" style="height: 34px">
                <asp:Button ID="AutoAssign" runat="server" OnClick="AutoAssign_Click" Text="Auto Assign" Width="112px" />
                <asp:Button ID="ManualButton" runat="server" OnClick="ManualButton_Click" Text="Manual" Width="112px" />
            </div>
            <table id="tableContent" border="1" runat="server"></table>
            <div id="ApplyDiv" draggable="auto" style="height: 34px">
                <asp:Button ID="Apply" runat="server" Text="Apply" Width="112px" OnClientClick="setTable();return false;" />

                <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager" runat="server" />
                    <asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional" ID="updatePanel1">
                        <ContentTemplate>
                            <asp:Button runat="server" Text="Save" Width="112px" ID="saveButton" Caption="Save" OnClientClick="UpdateArray();" OnClick="SaveButton_Click"/>
                        </ContentTemplate>    
                        <Triggers>
                            <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="saveButton" EventName="Click" />        
                        </Triggers>
                    </asp:UpdatePanel>

            </div>
        </div>

    </form>

</body>
```

Comment: How does it look like the UpdateArray method?

Comment: @AdrianIftode I removed it since it was just a test method with absolutely 0 impact on anything. I should have probably removed the hidden field as well since I didn't find it of any use.

Comment: You talk about a hidden field in your comment. That would be a good way to save the changes: store the relevant information in a hidden field (in your `UpdateArray` Javascript function) and retrieve the information from that field in `SaveButton_Click` on the server side. If that is what you had done, please post the code for `UpdateArray` and `SaveButton_Click`. Note: you cannot get the modified colors of the table cells on the server side.

Comment: @ConnorsFan I haven't wrote anything useful in the UpdateArray function, it just contains a random alert to indicate reaching the function. Regarding the rest of your sentence, I can't see a way of storing the "relevant information" in a hidden field, as I have no idea what to store and how to retrieve it properly and then how to update my array accordingly (which is my ultimate goal atm).

Comment: In your question, you say that "you lose the information that the table holds". If that is the information that you need to update your array, then that is the information (serialized in some way) that you should store in the hidden field. An alternative is to store in the hidden field the positions of the cells that were clicked and "replay" these clicks on the server side, using the same logic as on the client side.

Comment: @ConnorsFan storing the positions of the cells that were clicked in a hidden field sounds like something that should work. Not sure how difficult it will be to implement this though but I'll give it a try if there are no other easier alternatives. Thanks.

Comment: @ConnorsFan I ended up doing what you suggested and it worked! Server side is finally affected by changes I make in the client side, thank you so much!

Comment: You are welcome. Well done! :-)